# InfoPath start Microsoft Flow using http request

Tags: infopath, office-365, web-services, flow

I am having a few problems with Microsoft Flow and updating fields which then restarts the flow.

I am looking in to starting the flow instead by using a http request in Microsoft Flow and I want to trigger this when the submit button in the form is selected.

I have got the URL from Flow and tried to create a new data connection as a web service in InfoPath however it does not seem to accept the url.

Has anyone else had any experience of this?